# How can I get Ansible to group hosts based on Ansible facts?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I want to generate a report (probably using template) that groups my hosts based on facts about them.

Say I had the following servers in my `/etc/ansible/hosts` (`ansible_distribution` and `ansible_distribution_version` facts as specified in brackets):

```
mercer (RedHat, 7.2)
grocer (RedHat, 6.2)
draper (Solaris, 10)
fishmonger (RedHat, 7.2)
goldsmith (Solaris, 11)
skinner (RedHat, 7.2)
```

What I want to do is end up with a file looking like:

```
**RedHat 6.2 Servers**
grocer

**RedHat 7.2 Servers**
mercer
fishmonger
skinner

**Solaris 10 Servers**
draper

**Solaris 11 Servers**
goldsmith
```

I don't know whether it would be better to try:

A) looping through play_hosts and pulling out the facts and writing into a new variable as ('fact1', 'fact2', 'hostname') and then looping over that new variable with groupby within my jinja2 template to generate the report.

B) Sorting them all in an ansible task, and then handing a pre-grouped array of arrays to template, and formatting that.

... and I can't work out how to do either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a dynamic inventory script or the [group_by](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/group_by_module.html) inventory module to do this.  Let's go with the inventory module for now.  One issue here is that ansible_distribution_version needs to be normalized to a proper variable.  I would accomplish that with a filter.  Something like this

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - group_by:
      key: OSGROUP_{{ ansible_distribution_version | upper | regex_relace('(| |\.', '') }}
```

The regex probably isn't right but you get the idea.  Then later you can reference the group

```
- hosts: OSGROUP_REDHAT72
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="Do RedHat 7.2 stuff to {{inventory_name}}"
```

Comment: That sounds promising, but is there a way to loop over OSGROUP_*?

I'd prefer to write a single task in a very generalised way, rather than have one task per OS group - if nothing else, it would mean avoiding the need to add new tasks each time a new OS types come into the estate.

Comment: looks like the answer is to use something like the following:
    with_dict: groups
    when: 'OSGROUP_' in item.key
but haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: You can also run roles based on this grouping as well.  See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles.  Your when clause would look something like "when: inventory_hostname in groups['OSGROUP_REDHAT72']".  You could then repeat that line for each distro you're supporting

Comment: @PeterMabbott did you ever get the loop working over the hosts? I'm doing something similar where I group into AZs and update them either one at a time or spread across them as needed to maximise the availability of the application. I can't seem to get the right combination of with_dict and when to work as per your theory.